# Alternative solutions to Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 provider

Tags: c#, asp.net, oledb

I'm getting the **"Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 provider is not registered"** error on my asp.net application while I try to read an Excel file and after an exhaustive research on the web I just found myself in a dead-end. The only available solutions is to install the MS Component to achieve the objective. But there is a little inconvenient (as always), because of our costumer politics we can not install nothing but the application. And that's the real problem here. So I'm wondering if there is a way (an alternative way) to avoid the component installment.  If not well I think we will have a little issue with the client but nothing that we can not solve. But lets try to avoid that uncomfortable part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/).

I've used it for writing Excel files but it is also capable of reading Excel files too. It uses Open XML and it's easy to work with. Also, you do not need to install an OLEDB engine on the client machine.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will take a look at that component. Seems like its a flexible one.

Answer (score 1):

you do not need to install excel you should just be able to install the drivers.

2007 Office System Driver: Data Connectivity Components
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=23734

Comment: Currently we are reading 2007 excel files. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You havn't specified which version of the Excel format you want to read. You can use the [OpenXML SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5124) to read (and write) the newer formats. This SDK does not require that Excel is installed. Actually you don't need to install anything besides the assemblies you reference in your project.

The SDK is much more powerful than the OLEDB provider but it probably also requires more effort to use.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will look out for more info about that SDK. ATM we are running out of time so i can not spend it learning about it but for sure ill in the future.